# MS Access "Online Meeting" "Unknown Network error." When Opening

Tags: ms-access, general-network-error

So I have a `MSAccess` dB that is scheduled to open and run every 3 minutes. Immediately when it opens, a dialog window pops up as shown [image: here]. Through the task manager and services windows, I was able to see that it is being thrown by `MSAccess`. Online I could only find two references to this issue, unfortunately the answer is blocked unless you subscribe. [Ref 1](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27870149/when-openning-ms-access-an-online-meeting-error-occurs.html) [Ref 2](http://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21101682/Problem-with-shell-cmd.html). The process only will continue it you hit "ok", which defeats the reason for automating it. Does anyone know what and/or how to stop this?

Edit: I also should note that I looked through all of a `MSAccess` menu's and settings and could not find anything that appeared related to this.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
<System>
<Provider Name="Microsoft Office 14 Alerts" /> 
<EventID Qualifiers="0">300</EventID> 
<Level>4</Level> 
<Task>0</Task> 
<Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-02-05T14:53:52.000000000Z" /> 
<EventRecordID>1654</EventRecordID> 
<Channel>OAlerts</Channel> 
<Computer>OPTI-780-LJS2.boston.hembar.com</Computer> 
<Security />  
</System>
<EventData>
<Data>Online Meeting</Data> 
<Data>Unknown network error.</Data> 
<Data>701129</Data> 
<Data>14.0.7015.1000</Data> 
<Data /> 
<Data /> 
</EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Added the XML from Event Viewer.

Comment: What does your database do on startup? Does the message also appear when you open the DB manually?

Comment: @Andre, I'm assuming you mean after it opens? In that case an `AutoExec` macro starts and processes the rest of the routines. When I manually open the `dB` it starts without a hitch and works fine. Another thing I should note, in the `dB` itself, I have `SetWarninngs` to `False`. So I am thinking it is something before the `dB` fully opens, because otherwise it would be suppressed like the other notifications. I already checked for any problematic `add-ins` but found that there are none present, which eliminates that possibility.

Comment: Do you get any useful information if you leave `SetWarnings` on (True)?

Comment: Negative. Nothing related to this. Just the normal "You are about to append so many rows..."

Comment: I should probably note that in the `batch` file I use the following to call the `dB`

`start msaccess /C "C:\Users\ljs\Desktop\Stock_Automation_DO_NOT_EDIT\StockQuotes.accdb"` Could it be caused by the `/C`?

Comment: I can't find `/C` among the supported option for `start`.  Why did you include it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I copied the code from another snippet and didn't notice it was there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was it. Just tried running after removing the `/C` and it went through fine. I wonder why that was?

Comment: Funky. It's not interpreted by `start`, but by Access. `msaccess.exe /c` triggers the same message. Maybe some undocumented / obsolete switch to start an online meeting ("C"onnect)?